# How can I stop Facebook from knowing when I've seen a post?

Tags: facebook, privacy

There is a new feature I just found out about: Facebook publicizes when I've viewed a post on a group page. <strike>I'm not sure whether this is just for group pages or on friends either</strike>, but I'd like to be able to turn it off.

How can I do this?

Comment: Only group pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can't. it's probably possible for group admins only, however, you can leave the group and people will no longer know when you've seen a group post, even if you saw it before you left the group.